# asp.net url routers conflict with ajax webservice path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, url-routing, asp.net-routing

I have implemented ajax autocompleteExtender and it works well until i included asp.net url router.

this is ajax control

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" MinimumPrefixLength="1"  ServiceMethod="SearchText" ServicePath="~/WebService1.asmx"></cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

when  i included this line in global.asax.cs ,i am unable to retrieve methods in WebService1.asmx file

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("searchpage", "{categoryName}/{area}", "~/search.aspx");
```

how the servicepath should be? it is working in localhost but not in live environment.

thank you

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? It may be that your on IIS6 which is harder to get routing working on than IIS7

Comment: I would test it locally using IIS rather than the Visual Studio build in server to help on these matters.

Comment: Thanks for replying Andy. Its IIS/7.5  in live environment and V5.1 in localhost..

Comment: Hi Andy, found solution from your comments..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution :
include this in web.config

```
<system.webServer>  
  <handlers>     
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"/>  
      <remove name=" ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit "/>  
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

reference links :

[explanation link](http://business.troy.edu/Portal/using-aspnet-40-extension-less-routing-on-iis-75.aspx)

[main solution to refer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368)

thank you